# How to automatically generate REST endpoints from a file containing urls?

Tags: java, spring, api, swagger, documentation

I have a file that contains URLs that must be exposed on a REST API. All URLs represent distinct resources and they must be documented separately. The file contains hundreds of URLs like:

```
/p1
/p1/p2
/p1/p2/p3
/t1
/t1/t2
/t1/t2/t3
```

I want to automatically / programmatically generate REST endpoints so that I will be able to call:

```
GET on https://host/p1/
GET on https://host/p1/p2
GET on https://host/p1/p3

... and so on ...
```

The logic behind handling the requests is similar for every path, so /p1, /p1/p2, /t1, and so on can be handled by a single function that receives the entire path. In order to handle the request I have a function like this:

```
function handleRequest(url) {
    // this function should be called for every GET request on any of those endpoints
    // perform the business logic here 
}
```

Data is stored in a tree data structure, so it makes sense to get a path in the tree and return the data underneath the node the path points to. However, all of these paths are separate resources.

I am writing the code in Java, but the language is not important for now. I would generate a REST endpoint in Spring like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(
        path = "/t1",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        headers = "Accept=application/json"
    )
    public ResponseEntity getT1() {
       // handle request here
    }
```

However, since the number of resources that must be exposed through the API is very high, it is extremely hard to write a function like the one above for hundreds or thousands of times when the logic that handles the request is the same.

One solution that I found is to use [PathPatterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html). This would entail having a RequestMapping with a url like "/commonPath/**". The downside of this solution is that I cannot automatically generate documentation via Swagger for the API since there is a single entry point.

How can I automatically generate all these endpoints?

**Edit**

Documentation basically boils down to having an automatic way of telling what are the available endpoints the user can call. I do not want to write/maintain this manually since the number of URLs is very high. With Swagger, it is very simple. Just annotate the endpoints and a user interface is automatically generated for the clients of the API.

Comment: It sounds like there could be a template, where the @RequestMapping path value and the method name are placeholders which are populated/generated for each url.  The template could be a simple text file, or something more interesting like using [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/).

Comment: Since all those endpoints would effectively do the same, would it also be an option to create just a single endpoint that can handle all of those requests? What do you mean with "must be documented separately"? Should there be different documentation for each endpoint, and if so, where would that be coming from? Or does there rather have to be a way to see what would be valid requests? Could you have a second endpoint "get-resource-paths" for this?

Comment: Having a single endpoint / get-resource-paths would be fine if there would be an automatic way of generating which urls are available for the clients.

Comment: Your main problem seems to be the documentation: why don't you focus on generating the documentation from the given text file?

Answer (score 3):

I wish to know more details about your scenario but here are the possible options based on the given information at this point in time.

**Solution 1:**  If your input file is static and you need to expose the APIs based on the static input file then this solution may work well. Just write a program to generate the controller class based on the file.

```
@RestController
public class MyMultiPathApiController {

    @AutoWired
    private RestApiHandlerService restApiHandlerService

    @RequestMapping(
  value = { "/p1", "/p1/p2", "/p1/p2/p3" }, 
  method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> myMultiRestApi() {
        return restApiHandlerService.handleApiLogic();
    }
}
```

Alternatively request mapping accepts regular expressions as well. Based on the examples you have given you can come up with a regular expression as well.

**Solution 2 (Recommended Solution):**

If your file is expected to change and you want to expose API dynamically then you need to tweak the spring framework's `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`  class. Extend the class `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`  and write the logic which you want to write. You can read the file on the application start and cache it. You can refer to some examples on writing a custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping class [here](https://gist.github.com/UnquietCode/6323695).

I trust this information is helpful. Please let me know if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: I can't seem to wrap my head around RequestMappingHandlerMapping. I searched for working examples but I could not find one. Can you provide an example with code samples for the Solution2?

Comment: @Darkov - I have already provided a sample code example as part of my original post. Did you get a chance to look at them? Here is the link again in case if you have overlooked - https://gist.github.com/UnquietCode/6323695

Comment: I have posted my own version. I gave the bounty to this question because of the upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate the spring controllers using a java annotation processor coupled with either a templating framework like [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) or a java code emitter like [javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Lokesh for the answer. Unfortunately, I was not able to fully understand RequestMappingHandlerMapping and build a full working example. The answer is similar to @Andrew S suggestion in the comment.

I built a class that generates code for all the paths via 2 template files and saves the resulting java class in the project.

I have created a class template which is simply a text file:

```
package a.b.c.d;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Api (description = "Resource controller")
@RestController
@RequestMapping (path = "REQUEST_MAPPING_BASE_PATH")
public class Resources {
  REQUEST_METHODS
}
```

I have then created a method template which is also a text file:

```
@RequestMapping (
  path = "REQUEST_MAPPING_PATH",
  method = RequestMethod.REQUEST_HTTP_METHOD,
  produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE,
  consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE,
  headers = "Accept=application/json"
)
@ApiOperation (
  value = "REQUEST_METHOD_DESCRIPTION",
  response = ResponseEntity.class
)
public ResponseEntity REQUEST_METHOD_NAME (HttpServletRequest request) {
  String path = request.getRequestURI();
  return new GraphResourceHandler(path).execute();
}
```

GraphResourceHandler is the class that executes the logic for each path:

```
public class GraphResourceHandler {
    private final String path;

    public GraphResourceHandler(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public ResponseEntity execute() {
        //TODO implement logic
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

Generating the .java file with all resource is then trivial. I will only provide pseudocode:

```
class GenerateResources {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFileContainingPaths();
        
        // holds method definitions as string
        String methods = "";

        foreach(resource in paths) {
            //simply perform string replacement for variables in method template
            // eg. replace REQUEST_METHOD_NAME with a custom name
            methods += generateMethodFromResource(resource);
        }
        
        // replace REQUEST_METHODS variable to the contents of 'methods' variable
        addResourceMethodsToClassTemplate()
        writeResultingStringClassToJavaFile()
     }
}
```

Compile the project and there you go. Of course, whenever you add a new value to the file, this class must be rerun, but I think it can be further automated. The advantage is that I don't have to write thousands of lines of code and that Swagger knows how to generate the resources automatically.